# NSPredicate search LIKE

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

i'm trying to filter a string array with this predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF LIKE[c] '#*!%d'", aNumber]
```

Every string which is like #WILDCARD!ANY_NUMBER is valid.

But it doesn't work :(
Can you help me?

EDIT:

```
NSString *pattern = [@"#*!" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", numberVariable];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern];
NSArray *filteredArray = [anArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

The array anArray contains Strings like #0!-1 (numberVariable is -1) but the array filterdArray is empty. So the regex doesn't work.

EDIT:

My Solution:

```
NSString *pattern = [@"#.*!\\" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", numberVariable];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", pattern];
NSArray *filteredArray = [anArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: You use `%d` if `aNumber` is of `int` type. And what is #*?

Comment: What's 'aNumber' for if your description says you're trying to match against any number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all strings that look like "#ANY_CHARACTERS!ANY_NUMBER" with an *arbitrary number*, you need the "MATCHES" operator with a regular expression:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"#.*!\\d+"];
NSArray *filtered = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

If you have a specific number `aNumber` and want to find all strings of the form 
"#ANY_CHARACTERS!<aNumber>", then the following should work:

```
NSString *pattern = [@"#*!" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", aNumber];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF LIKE %@", pattern];
NSArray *filtered = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

The problem with your

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF LIKE[c] '#*!%d'", aNumber]
```

is that `%d` *inside quotation marks* is not replaced by `aNumber`.

Comment: Thank you.. but that doesn't work :-/ i edited the post with my new code.. any idea?

Comment: @Maik639: You did not copy my second code example exactly, it should be "SELF LIKE" and not "SELF MATCHES" in that case.

Comment: Okay.. Your updated post helped me a lot. I updated the post with my solution. Thank you!